# How to create an executable (.exe) Python program that also uses the PyGame library

Tags: python, pygame, exe, executable

guys. I'm new to StackOverflow and Python. I've recently recreated the Snake game using Python and PyGame library. The thing is, that I want to send the game to someone as an executable (.exe). So that when that person recieves the file he can run the game by opening "Snake.exe" in his Windows machine. I only used 2 .py files and a scores.txt file to store the High Score. I would appreciate any help :) Thanks in advance.

(Note: I coded the game using PyCharm Community)

I attach the following screenshots:

[Files in my project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ca7v.png)

[My game welcome screen (why not)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQBvE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like auto_py_to_exe. Install it using pip with `pip install auto_py_to_exe`. then open it with `python -m auto_py_to_exe` in command prompt. You can then add the 2 .py scripts, the .txt and any other files needed. [Link](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/#description) to website for other downloading options